# How to get parent classes of class in my meta class?

Tags: inheritance, python-3.x, metaprogramming, metaclass, python-datamodel

I have the [following script](http://ideone.com/XFRDr5):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

class MyMeta(type):
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, dct):
        print(name + " " + str(bases))
        return super(MyMeta, mcs).__new__(mcs, name, bases, dct)


class A(metaclass=MyMeta):
    def foo(self):
        pass


class B(A):
    pass


class C(B):
    def foo(self):
        pass


def main():
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I get the following output:

```
A ()
B (<class '__main__.A'>,)
C (<class '__main__.B'>,)
```

But I expect it:

```
A ()
B (<class '__main__.A'>,)
C (<class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.A'>)
```

Where I make a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bases` parameter list base classes listed in the class definition.

It seems like you want [`class.mro`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#class.mro):

```
class MyMeta(type):
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, dct):
        ret = super(MyMeta, mcs).__new__(mcs, name, bases, dct)
        print(name + " " + str(ret.mro()[1:-1]))
        return ret
```